# How do I make my lists persistant despite stopping the app?

Tags: android

I'm making my first Android app and I ran into a problem with the lists I use. The list is populated by the app and user can add new items to it.

Everything works fine until I stop the app and launch it again. The user's items are not there.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, g.getListDataHeader(), g.getListDataChild());
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("medicineHeaderList", g.getListDataHeader());
    savedInstanceState.putSerializable("medicineHashMap", g.getListDataChild());
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
    g.setListDataHeader(savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("medicineHeaderList"));
    g.setListDataChild((HashMap<String, Medicine>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("medicineHashMap"));
}

private void prepareListData() {

    g = Globals.getInstance();
    // Adding child data
    if (g.getListDataHeader().isEmpty()) {
        g.addToList("someMed");
        g.addToList("someMed2");

        g.putToHashMap(g.getListDataHeader().get(0), new Medicine("someMed", "someComp", 2, new BigDecimal("20.55")));
        g.putToHashMap(g.getListDataHeader().get(1), new Medicine("someMed2", "someComp2", 4, new BigDecimal("15.20")));
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
public class Medicine implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String company;
private int dosage;
private BigDecimal price;

public Medicine (String name, String company, int dosage, BigDecimal price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.company = company;
    this.dosage = dosage;
    this.price = price;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(2, 31).
            append(getName()).
            append(getCompany()).
            append(getDosage()).
            append(getPrice()).
            toHashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof Medicine))
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;

    Medicine rhs = (Medicine) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder().
            append(getName(), rhs.getName()).
            append(getCompany(), rhs.getCompany()).
            append(getDosage(), rhs.getDosage()).
            append(getPrice(), rhs.getPrice()).
            isEquals();
}


private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
    oos.defaultWriteObject();
    List medicine = new ArrayList();
    medicine.add(name);
    medicine.add(company);
    medicine.add(dosage);
    medicine.add(price);
    oos.writeObject(medicine);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    ois.defaultReadObject();
    List medicine = (List)ois.readObject();
    name = (String) medicine.get(0);
    company = (String) medicine.get(1);
    dosage = (Integer) medicine.get(2);
    price = (BigDecimal) medicine.get(3);
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public int getDosage() {
    return dosage;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

}

and :

```
public class Globals {

private static Globals instance = null;
private ArrayList<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
private HashMap<String, Medicine> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, Medicine>();

private Globals(){}

public void addToList(String medicineName) {
    getListDataHeader().add(medicineName);
}

public void putToHashMap(String key, Medicine value) {
    getListDataChild().put(key, value);
}

 public ArrayList<String> getListDataHeader() {
    return listDataHeader;
}

public HashMap<String, Medicine> getListDataChild() {
    return listDataChild;
}

public static synchronized Globals getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Globals();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setListDataHeader(ArrayList<String> listDataHeader) {
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
}

public void setListDataChild(HashMap<String, Medicine> listDataChild) {
    this.listDataChild = listDataChild;
}
}
```

There are some things from mixed tutorials and stack overflow answers and I tried hard to make this work but I can't and I can't find my mistake here. Why doesn't it save the instance when I kill the app?

I get the feeling now that I don't understand how it should work at all and where it should magically be saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods are not meant to persist data permanently. They are used to recreate an activity due to configuration changes or when it is killed to recover system memory. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html):

> When your activity is destroyed because the user presses Back or the
>   activity finishes itself, the system's concept of that Activity
>   instance is gone forever because the behavior indicates the activity
>   is no longer needed. However, if the system destroys the activity due
>   to system constraints (rather than normal app behavior), then although
>   the actual Activity instance is gone, the system remembers that it
>   existed such that if the user navigates back to it, the system creates
>   a new instance of the activity using a set of saved data that
>   describes the state of the activity when it was destroyed.

If you want to persist data permanently, you should look into using a SQLite database or saving data to SharedPreferences.